# can I have my own database connection and tables in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've created my own theme using HTML, CSS, JS which contains FORM (Emp_ID,Emp_Name, Address etc) . It has database connectivity with MySql. I've written database connectivity in PHP using simple PHP script and MySql query. I am going to convert this theme into the wordpress theme; but wondering how to use my MySql database in wordpress. Can anybody show me the basic and easy way to do it. If you know any easy available tutorial, please let me know. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance. Cheers ... :(

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Did you search for it, because Wordpress is well documented. You certainly arent the first plugin developer, there must be other people who have had the same problems as you!

Comment: You can re-use your PHP code in a wordpress theme. Wordpress themes are PHP code.

Comment: @TJHeuvel: As I said, any help is appreciated; whether its nothing or something. I've messed up myself with a lot of contents on internet. neway, thanks for your valuable time. I've of course checked those documents which looks tricky for a newcomers but will keep looking into it until I learn it. Thanks...

Comment: for independant database connections you can create custom wordpress templates, create a page in the admin to look at this template and that can do your processing. there is no need to test for a db connection if you have included the get_header() function too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[this page may help](http://www.devlounge.net/code/wordpress-plugins-and-database-interaction) otherwise you can just use your same code to interact with the wordpress database negating wordpress's methods. (though you have to be carefull to prevent sql injection etc via your form, as you wont have the securities of the wordpress db methods)

Comment: - as per warnings it might be worth reading an overview of MVC and its benefits too... (hint wordpress methods/classes use this)